# Vertex deform in mesh animation

Tags: animation, bones, vertex-groups

I've made a gun model and decided to make a simple shoot animation for practice.
I set up the vertex groups and bones (I'm working with vertex groups). But when I move the bone in pose mode. I get weird deformation. Some vertex follow the bone better than the other ones.

Original state...
[image: before bone moves]

Now I move the bone...
[image: after bone moved]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take a look at the MarkDown [formatting guide](http://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks). You will see that you can easily make a line brake with two spaces.